# Stretch and skew cubes with geometry nodes/raycast

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have just started out with geometry nodes and have an idea that I wonder if somebody could help me with. The idea is to add cubes that stretch until they hit an object (wall/roof/floor) and also skew if the object they hit is not parallell to the face of the cube.

In this image I show the cube in orange and the red cube is the result I would like to get. Any ideas how to get started?

[image]

Comment: you should checkout the raycast node - it can determine when it hits and give you the normal

Comment: Hello, it looks like you're using the BlenderBIM addon ? It has a builtin tool to generate spaces from closed walls.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I plan to use the raycast node but I have not been able to solve this using the examples I have found. At some point I would like to be able to generate IFCSPaces from walls using BlenderBIM but right now there are too many limitations (for example, my spaces are not closed and consists out of other room bounding objects so I thought I find an alternative method,